# Sonar does not pick up Unit Tests Results even thought Code Coverage is generated

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am running SonarQuebe 6.2 on my local machine, I have Spring Boot Java 8 project with written unit tests that I want to upload to Sonar for static analysis all together with code coverage.
Code coverage is generated - I have my JaCoCo HTML report, JUnit XML test files are generated but my Sonar seems to miss Unit Tests result even thought that Code Coverage is diplayed:
pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.facebook4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>facebook4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    </execution>
                 <execution>
                    <id>generate-code-coverage-report</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=org.eventizer:EventizerServer
sonar.projectName=EventizerServer
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.log.level=DEBUG

sonar.sources=src/main/

sonar.language=java
sonar.java.source=1.8

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.java.binaries=target/classes/org/eventizer/eventizerserver/
sonar.java.test.binaries=target/test-classes/org/eventizer/eventizerserver/
sonar.tests=src/test/

sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=target/jacoco.exec
sonar.junit.reportPaths=target/surefire-reports/
```

I am running this mvn command:
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
As a result I am getting target directory with following output:
[image: Target output directory]

Classes directory that is set for `sonar.java.binaries`:
[image]

Test classes directory that is set for `sonar.java.test.binaries`:
[image]

Surefire JUnit test reports directory that is set for     `sonar.junit.reportPaths`:
[image]

JaCoCo report output directory:
[image]

JaCoCo HTML report in browers:
[image]

After that I am running `sonar-scanner.bat`, below some important (I tihnk so) outputs:
[image]
[image]

My Sonar web instance project analysis:
[image]

And I really do not have idea why this is happening since it looks like everything got generated properly. Since yesterday I think I have tried everything on StackOverflow so please do not mark it as duplicate.
This is even weirder because when I access Coverage metrics for this project I can see that 100% Unit tests passed:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Well... I suppose, that could because of `sonar.sources=src/main/`... If you set it as `sonar.sources=src`, it will show again.

And, I just find there's a [Sonar Parater](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters):
`sonar.tests=src/test` will show the junit report in sonar.

here's my sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=com.test.marslo:marslo-test
sonar.projectName=marslo-test
sonar.projectVersion=1.1.0

sonar.projectBaseDir=.
sonar.sources=src/main
sonar.tests=src/test
sonar.java.binaries=build

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.java.source=1.8

sonar.jacoco.reportPaths=./build/jacoco/test.exec
sonar.junit.reportPaths=./build/test-results/test
```

And the build.gradle:

```
...
apply plugin: "jacoco"

...
...

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.0"
}

jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled true
        csv.enabled true
        html.enabled true
    }
}

test {
    jacoco {
        append = false
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec")
        classDumpDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps")
    }
}
```

Build with:

```
gradle clean build test jacocoTestReport
```

Comment: Thanks, its helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I have discovered something that may be a Sonar bug.

Basically, this project has been pushed to Sonar for a long time with basic `mvn sonar:sonar` configuration. So, it was not even doing test results. Now I wanted to run that via Jenkins, so I filled all necessary fields in `sonar-project.properties` and pushed via `Sonar-Runner` not `mvn sonar:sonar`.

After doing so as you could see, Unit Tests Quality gate was failing with no good reason. Because in my latest screenshoot, you can see that in fact Unit Tests passed 100.0%.

I decide to push that analysis to a separate project by changing `projectKey` property to something else and all of the sudden everything went smoothly.